Xcode: Package Resolution Failed
I am trying to add packages to my Xcode project but it continuously showing me the same error Package Resolution Failed, Package could not be resolved. I have tried to add the package to other projects there are working fine but for this specific project it continuously showing me this error.


I have tried with Reset Package Caches, Resolve Package Versions and Update to Latest Package Versions nothing works for me any idea ?
[Updated Issue] I found that the issue is due to firebase-ios-sdk. If I remove this package everything working perfectly and then If I tried to add this package then it continuously showing me this error for firebase Package Resolution Failed
[Xcode 15.3]

Same here, tried a lot, not avail
